# Is there a website that can tell whether a word or phrase is formal or informal?

Tags: formality

Is there a website that can tell whether a word or phrase is formal or informal?

For example, I would like to know if "before long" is formal or informal, and if it is informal, what its formal counterpart is.

Thanks!

Comment: [*Merriam-Webster's Online Dictionary*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before%20long) perhaps? Any dicitonary would do; words and phrase are marked *obsolete, archaic, informal, colloquial, dialectal, non-standard,* etc. M-W calls them [usage labels](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/dictnotes/usage.htm). If it's not marked at all, then consider it to be Standard English.

Comment: So what about the example "before long", http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before+long?show=0&t=1386542162

Comment: If you click my first link, it brings you to the same place that you've linked. I was trying to do the work for you ;) Read the usage notes page if you're unsure about what to look for. I was trying to tell you that it's Standard English in my first comment though.

Answer (score 3):

As John Q Public says, you should start by consulting a dictionary: a good one will usually tell you if your word or phrase is objectionable in formal use.

However, there are degrees of formality, and even in scholarly works different disciplines draw the formal/informal line in different places. Scientific and mathematical papers usually do not accommodate much departure from the strictest formality; critical and historical papers  are much more open to colloquialism and humor.

A good followup to what the dictionary tells you is to search the expression on Google Books, perhaps accompanied by a keyword which will turn up works in your field. If you find that hits only occur in dialog or popular non-fiction, you should probably shy away from using it in formal work. But if you find the expression in scholarly works in your field it is probably safe (unless you usually find it in quotation marks).

For instance, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22before+long%22&oq=%22before+long%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6149j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22before+long%22+anthropology&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099) is a GB search on ["before long" anthropology]; as you see, it returns lots of hits, including textbooks and monographs. Many of these hits, it is true, show up in biographical and historical studies; but after all, you would expect the expression to show up in narrative rather than descriptive passages.

The best model for your own language will always be works by established authorities or masters in the field in which you are writing, addressing audiences like those you are addressing.

Comment: Very solid advice. One word comes to mind: voice. In narratives, *before long* works quite well, whereas in a scholarly paper, it might be too imprecise. It's often difficult to explain, but you want to echo the voices of the authorities on the subject you're writing about without directly imitating or copying them. In other words, your work should read as other bodies of work within that field do.

Comment: In StoneyB's answer, Will someone tell the use of "...will always **be works** by established..."?

Comment: @MaulikV *Works* here means "written works"--papers, articles, books. *Established authorities* means "writers whose authority as experts has been established".

Comment: @StoneyB. Oh, I couldn't see that! Thanks. An article 'the' could have clarified that. "....will always be **the** works by....". Is it necessary to put *the* there since we are talking about a noun and not a verb *works*? I think I'll learn a lot here. :)

Comment: @MaulikV *The* works would suggest specific works, but I wanted to leave room for each reader to consider whatever authorities, and whatever works by those authorities, are most worthy of being imitated in their own field.