# humankind and well-off

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, usage, formal-language

Are word "humankind" and "well-off" formal or not?

Can I use, for instance, in academic writing so:

- ***Humankind*** has all possibilities to make all people ***well-off***

And are there any web sites when I can check either some words are formal or not?

(Sometimes "Cambridge Dictionary" provides this information, but not in any cases.)

Comment: *Well off* shouldn't have a hyphen as a complement.[¹](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-off) Yes, CED marks some words "formal" (e.g. [*notwithstanding*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notwithstanding)), so you should also know words without that marking are not so formal; however, this word isn't marked "informal" (e.g. [*bro*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bro)) either. This means it can still be used in formal contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a website that can tell whether a word or phrase is formal or informal?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14149/is-there-a-website-that-can-tell-whether-a-word-or-phrase-is-formal-or-informal)

Comment: @niamulbengali Speaking frankly, it doesn't. For, in this question all people advised to check different dictionaries. I've checked my words there, but there were nothing either it's formal or not.

Comment: That means the word is neither formal nor informal. Would you say any word that isn't formal is informal? No, because these are two ends of a spectrum, and most words fall somewhere in between. For example, *cat* doesn't have either marking.[¹](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/car) This just means you can use it (and *humankind* and *well off*) in an academic paper just as you would in a blog or newspaper article. They don't have an affinity to either extreme.